# Connecting to SSH over the internet on ubuntu-core

Tags: ssh, internet, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I need to communicate with my raspberry pi model 4B over the internet with ssh. However, currently, my ssh connection only works on a local network. How can I make the ssh connection working over the internet?

Comment: Look up *port forwarding*. Set up port forwarding on your router. Your router, not your Ubuntu Core system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup Zerotier on both the servers and then connect through there.

No opening ports to the internet

[Guide can be found here](https://breadnet.co.uk/zerotier-cloud-managment/?pk_campaign=Stackexchange&pk_kwd=ssh)

Comment: This answer relies mostly on the provided link.  Perhaps provide a Wayback link?